# PHP MYSQL Save search query into database

Tags: php, mysql

I have search on my site where user can search in titles, description and select categories.

I wont to save the search into database but only if user wonts to save it.

This is my link which save into database.
domain.com/save/?action=save&reference=SEARCH_QUERY.

but because i have title&description&cat.

It stop at & save the first part of the query.

How can i save this in to database including the & as i need to get this back so user can go back to save search query later on.

I have used htmlentities and htmlspecial but still it turns into & but first char is &.

Comment: try `urlencode` and then `urldecode` when you got to use the saved query.

Comment: Sorry i dont know what that was but i do that now. Thank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you need `urlencode`:

```
echo urlencode('title=t&description=d&cat=c');
```

results in

```
title%3Dt%26description%3Dd%26cat%3Dc
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [urlencode](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.urlencode.php) to encode parameter that are passed in the URL.

htmlentities and htmlspecialchars are function that are used to espace string that will end up in HTML code, not in URL.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're looking for [`urlencode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php)?